# How to modify Gnome-Shell animations?

Tags: gnome, effects, mutter

I use docky in Gnome-Shell and it's annoying that when I minimise a window, it goes up to the top left corner. I know mutter isn't that customisable but is it possible to get a minimise effect similar to that of Cinnamon, here the window just shrinks  and disappears? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't simply change the animations. I had a time when I wanted to do that. If you want to change the animations for gnome-shell. You'll have to change the code for the window manager itself. I know it sucks.

Answer (score 3):

example>
sudo vi /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/windowManager.js

find method

```
      _minimizeWindow : function(shellwm, actor) { ...
```

and.. you can see that

```
            xDest = monitor.x;
            yDest = monitor.y;

            if (Clutter.get_default_text_direction() == Clutter.TextDirection.RTL)
                xDest += monitor.width;
            xScale = 0;
            yScale = 0;
```

change like this!

```
            xDest = window.x;
            yDest = window.y;

            xScale = 1;
            yScale = 0;
```

roll up window animation ^^

:: Warning! ::

If your syntax is wrong, you may break your GUI completely.
In that case, you have to use Alt+Ctrl+F1 and rollback.

Comment: You failed to mention when changes take effect. Reboot or logout, then login?

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/windowManager.js`
The function you're looking for is WindowManager's `_minimizeWindow`.
Changing `xDest` and `yDest` properly will meet your requirement, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shell extension for changing some aspects of it :

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/277/impatience/

but not the roll up speed