# virt-manager guest OS not grabbing key bindings on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, 22.10, virt-manager

I have recently noticed that when I press key bindings like `super`, `ALT` + `TAB` and etc.  It activates my host OS instead of my guest OS.

So when I try to go to the applications menu on my guest by pressing `super` it just goes to the applications menu on my host instead, same with `ALT` + `TAB`.

This happens with all my VMs and even in if I run a new VM with Ubuntu installer in a VM with all default settings.

System details:

> OS Name: Ubuntu 22.10
>
> GNOME Version: 43.20
>
> Windowing System: Wayland
>
> Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 / NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660

VM software details:

> virt-manager version: 4.1.0
>
> QEMU Version: 1:7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu2

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/6107) in GNOME shell ([Ubuntu bug 1998017](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1998017)). It has been [fixed](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/merge_requests/2548) upstream, but the fix hasn't made its way into Ubuntu yet.

As a workaround, I was starting virt-manager from the command line using X instead of Wayland (`WAYLAND_DISPLAY= virt-manager`).

But just today, I [discovered](https://askubuntu.com/a/1317692/1656135) that you can actually patch this yourself fairly easily since it's a javascript file. Basically, it boiled down to this:

1. `mkdir -p ~/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays/ui`
2. `echo 'export G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS="/org/gnome/shell=$HOME/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays"' >> ~/.profile`
3. `gresource extract /usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so /org/gnome/shell/ui/inhibitShortcutsDialog.js > ~/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays/ui/inhibitShortcutsDialog.js`
4. `$EDITOR ~/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays/ui/inhibitShortcutsDialog.js # manually patch`

You can see the patch to apply [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/merge_requests/2548/diffs?commit_id=b0befbbfbbe4a335f6c184049743202e91fcdfe8). In theory I would think you can log out and back in to see the results, but I went ahead and rebooted just to be sure. I've only been running with this patch for a few hours, but so far so good.

I plan to comment out the line in `.profile` any time GNOME Shell is updated. Then repeat steps 3 and 4. If the patch is still needed, uncomment the line in `.profile` to continue using the patch. If it's no longer needed, then clean everything up and return to the Ubuntu version without the patch.